# Eigenvectors to find invariant lines that do not pass through the origin

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image: -al]
[image]

Above is a solution to a problem given by a textbook. I want to know whether this approach can be used to find invariant lines that do not pass through the origin in any case, or if this is a special case. If it was the case that the first eigenvector was $(1,0)$, would all points on the x axis be invariant? Which would lead to the same result that any $y=x+k$ is invariant. What if the first eigenvector was $(4,3)$, or something arbitrary, could I use the fact that points along that eigenvector are invariant to find invariant lines? How would this not lead to the same conclusion that $y=x+k$ is invariant? Similarly, what about when the first eigenvector presents another invariant line that involves y(i.e not x=c or y=c)?

Answer (score 1):

A line $\ell\subset\Bbb R^2$ can be described as the set
$$
\vec w+\alpha\vec v\qquad\alpha\in\Bbb R
$$
where $0\neq\vec v$ and $\vec w$ are two vectors. The line $\ell$ will contain $0$ exactly when the vectors $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ are parallel,  which we assume not.

Let $T:\Bbb R^2\rightarrow\Bbb R^2$ be a linear transformation with associated matrix $A$ with respect to some choice of basis. Assume that $T$ has maximal rank, i.e. $\det A\neq 0$. You want to know when $T(\ell)=\ell$.

Since the vector $\vec v$ gives the direction of $\ell$ a necessary condition is that $T(\vec v)=\lambda\vec v$, i.e. that $\vec v$ is an eigenvector of $T$.

Given this, you'll have $T(\ell)=\ell$ exactly when $T(\vec w)\in\ell$, i.e. $T(\vec w)=\vec w+\alpha\vec v$ for some $\alpha\in\Bbb R$, i.e. the question reduces to the solvability of the linear system with a parameter $\alpha$
$$
(A-I)\vec w=\alpha\vec v.
$$
When $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ the matrix $A-I$ has maximal rank, so the given system has always a solution.

If $1$ is an eigenvalue and $v$ is the "other" eigenvector, i.e. $\lambda\neq1$ the linear system can be rewritten as
$$
(A-I)(\vec w-\frac{\alpha}{1-\lambda}\vec v)=0
$$
and a solution exists for exactly one value of $\alpha$.

Last, if $\lambda=1$ we may assume without loss of generality that $\vec v=\vec e_1$ (standard basis) so that a fixed line can only be "horizontal". They will be fixed by $T$ if and only if
$$
T(\vec e_2)=a\vec e_1+\vec e_2
$$
(any $a\in \Bbb R$). This last case is "geometrically obvious".